# Toggle a list of Lables based on checkbox react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that has a array of cars, i am showing a list of labels with all the car names, i want to default the list to just show diesel cars. I then want a checkbox to toggle showall (defaults to false) when clicked shows all the cars

```
interface ICars
{
    name: string;
    isDiesel: boolean;
    key: string
}

let cars: ICar[];

const carLabels = () => {
    const carQuery = getData<ICarWrapper>({ query: QUERY, variables: {} });
    cars = (carQuery as IServiceLoaded<ICarWrapper>).payload?.cars;
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
        <>
            <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox name="checkedC" />} label="Show All" />
            <Paper elevation={0} className={classes.paperRoot}>
            { ! carQuery.loading &&
                    cars?.filter(x => x.isDiesel).map((car: ICar, idx: number) =>
                <Chip key={idx} size="small" className={classes.chip} color="primary" label={car.name} avatar={<Avatar>{car.key}</Avatar>}/>
                )
            }
        </Paper>
        </>
    );
};

export default carLabels;
```

What i am missing is using the usestate and then toggling the checkbox to showall or just show diesel depending if it is checked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your filter dependent on the checkbox selection and track the current checkbox in a useState.

```
const carLabels = () => {
    const [filterDiesel, setFilter] = React.useState(true);
    const carQuery = getData<ICarWrapper>({ query: QUERY, variables: {} });
    cars = (carQuery as IServiceLoaded<ICarWrapper>).payload?.cars;
    const classes = useStyles();
    if(cars  && filterDiesel) {
        cars = cars.filter(car => car.isDiesel);
    }
    return(
        <>
            <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox
                checked={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {setFilter(e.target.checked}}
                value={filterDiesel}
                name="checkedC" />}label="Show All" />
            <Paper elevation={0} className={classes.paperRoot}>
            { ! carQuery.loading &&
                    cars?.map((car: ICar, idx: number) =>
                <Chip key={idx} size="small" className={classes.chip} color="primary" label={car.name} avatar={<Avatar>{car.key}</Avatar>}/>
                )
            }
        </Paper>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: works perfectly thanks, only issue is when it loads the checkbox isnt checked when it should be?